# my OpenCV color detection (red) program doesn't work. it detects all colors instead of red

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, color-detection

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('image.jpg')

hsvFrame=cv2.cvtColor(img ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#SET RANGE FOR RED
#DEFINE MASk

red_lower=np.array([0,0,204],np.uint8)
red_upper=np.array([0,0,255],np.uint8)
red_mask=cv2.inRange(hsvFrame,red_lower,red_upper)
kernel=np.ones((5,5),"uint8")
red_mask=cv2.dilate(red_mask,kernel)
res_red=cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=red_mask)

#creating contour

contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(red_mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for pic,contour in enumerate(contours):

    area=cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area>300:
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        imageFrame=cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

        cv2.putText(img,"red colour",(x,y),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.0,(0,0,255))

cv2.imshow("detected red ",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

tried to detect red color in a given image but the program detects other colors. converted this program from a program that detects red color from the webcam feed and it works fine, but the red detection in images doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you converting your image to HSV?  There appears to be a mismatch between the color range you are trying to match (which appears to be specified in BGR color space) vs the color space your image is in (HSV).  I suspect that is the source of your issue.